# How do I remove UTC offset (timezone) value from a timestamp in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm using CTAS method to create a redshift table. timestamp value in One of the column is generated using
`to_timestamp(substring(min(to_char(xyz,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||to_char(abc,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')),15),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')`

The value in a table is being stored as `2023-02-25 19:55:27.000 -0600`  with an UTC offset.

When a person read the same column from EST (I'm in CST), he/she read it as `2023-02-25 20:55:27.000 -0500` which is not expected.

I want everyone across the globe read it without an offset value as `2023-02-25 19:55:27.000`

I have tried following:

I created timestamp value as

`to_timestamp(substring(min(to_char(xyz,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||to_char(abc,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')),15),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')::timestamp`

and I see it gets stored without an offset value as `2023-02-25 19:55:27.000`. But when I read the same column through a view (a simple view on the table), I get the timestamp with offset again. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: You can use AT TIME ZONE function in redshift.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_AT_TIME_ZONE.html

`select to_char(your_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as new_timestamp from your_table;`

Comment: @Tushar thanks for your comment, when I `cast` it back to timestamp the offset value returns.  I prefer to keep it as `timestamp` rather than a string type.

Comment: Ohk, Can you use as :
`select
    CAST(your_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' as TIMESTAMP) AS new_timestamp 
from your_table;`

Can you please tell me if it resolved your issue

Answer (score 0):

To_timestamp() creates a value of timestampTZ.  You will need to cast your value to timestamp to get a timestamp without timezone.

This is what @Tushar is trying to get across.  The timezone representation you are seeing is due to the data type your are creating with your CTAS.  This is the downside of CTAS - you get the implied data type, not necessarily the data type you really want.

Just be careful that you don’t change the time value when you do the casting.  This is also what @Tushar is helping with.